# Generating a random number using components in Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to generate a random number on a ng-click event. Currently it is generating a random number, however only once, and it then relies on a browser refresh to then generate another number.

I believe it may have something to do with the way that I am declaring the variable sample.

```
angular.module('FOO', [])
  .component('foo', {
    controller: fooController,
    controllerAs: 'foo',
    template: template()
});

function template() {
  return [

  '<button ng-repeat="move in foo.moves" ng-click="foo.gameplay(move)" >',
    '{{ move }}',
  '</button>',

 ].join('')
}

function fooController() {
  var self = this;

  self.gameplay = gameplay;
  self.moves = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
  var sample = Math.floor(Math.random() * (self.moves.length));

  function gameplay(clicker) {
    console.log(sample);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function fooController() {
  var self = this;

  self.gameplay = gameplay;
  self.moves = ['var1', 'var2', 'var3']
  var sample = Math.floor(Math.random() * (self.moves.length));

  function gameplay(clicker) {
    sample = Math.floor(Math.random() * (self.moves.length));
    console.log(sample);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use

```
function gameplay(clicker) {
  var sample = Math.floor(Math.random() * (self.moves.length));
  console.log(sample);
}
```

Comment: This will not work when load first...it will only work after click

Comment: As soon as I saw this suggestion I immediately saw what I was doing wrong.

Where it was previously was acting as a constructor so when it was clicked once it would only be allocated once.

Thank you